# TIC TAC TOE javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Creating a tic tac toe game. I am trying to read columns and rows of the tic tac toe to check who won. I am using `$scope.checkResults()` to grab the columns and rows and pass them into the `allTheSame` function to check if the values are equal which is not working.
Here is the codepen link. http://codepen.io/theMugician/pen/ojJrRp

```
var app = angular.module("ticTacToe", []);
app.controller("MainCtrl", function($scope){
  var cell = $(".square");
  $scope.player = "";
  $scope.AI = "";
  // changed special chars to X and O as the if statement failed.
  var cross = "✖";
  var circle = "◯";

  /*** Choose a shape ***/
  $scope.choosePlayer = function(e) {
  $scope.player = $(e.currentTarget).text();
        $('.choose').css('top', '-2000px');
        $('#wrapper').css('top', '-600px');
        $('#wrapper').css('opacity', '1');
    //these if statements failed before (AI was always empty)
    if($scope.player === cross){
    $scope.AI = circle;
    }else if($scope.player === circle){
    $scope.AI = cross;
  }
}

  /*** Shape Cells ***/
  $scope.cells = [ { value: '' }, { value: '' }, { value: '' }, 
     { value: '' }, { value: '' }, { value: '' } ,
    { value: '' }, { value: '' }, { value: '' }  
  ];
  // made a ref to scope cells
  $scope.emptyCells = $scope.cells;

  /*** Make a move ***/
  $scope.move = function(cell){
    cell.value = $scope.player;
    var round = 0;
    /*** AI makes a move ***/
    while(round < 1){
     // filtered to get only available cells (for performance)
      $scope.emptyCells = $scope.cells.filter(function(cell){
        return cell.value === '';
      });
      // got random cell according to empty cells
      var randomCell =  $scope.emptyCells[Math.floor((Math.random()*($scope.emptyCells.length-1))+1)];
      if(randomCell.value === "" ){
      randomCell.value = $scope.AI;
      round = 1;
      }else{
        round = 0;
      } 
    }
  $scope.checkResults();
  };

  //checks if values are the same
  function allthesame(arr){
    var L= arr.length-1;
    while(L){
        if(arr[L--]!==arr[L]) return false;
    }
    alert(arr[L].value + "is the winner");
}

  //checks Columns and rows
  $scope.checkResults = function(){
    var allCells = $scope.cells;
    // check rows
     var cellRows = [];
    while(allCells > 0){
      cellRows.push(allCells.splice(0,3));
    }
      for(var i = 0; i < cellRows.length; i++){
        allTheSame(cellRows[i]);
      }
    // check columns
       var cellCols = [];
         while(allCells > 0){
          cellCols.push(allCells.splice(0));
          cellCols.push(allCells.splice(3));
          cellCols.push(allCells.splice(6));
      }
      while(cellCols > 0){
      cellCols.push(cellCols.splice(0,3));
    }
      for(var i = 0; i < cellCols.length; i++){
        allTheSame(cellCols[i]);
      }
  }

$scope.reset = function(){
  $scope.cells = [ { value: '' }, { value: '' }, { value: '' }, 
     { value: '' }, { value: '' }, { value: '' } ,
    { value: '' }, { value: '' }, { value: '' }  
  ];
}
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you have an array of 9 values and need to compare to 8 possible winning arrangements, 3 vertical, 3 horizontal and 2 diagonal..  an array iteration against the follow list of "winning" combinations might be what you want to do.

```
{0,1,2}
{3,4,5}
{6,7,8}
{0,3,6}
{1,4,7}
{2,5,8}
{0,4,8}
{2,4,6}
```

I was just on my way out the door I can post some code later but I think saving this list as a comparison item for your cells might be the easier method.

Here is a reference article I grabbed quickly: this should be easy to convert to javascript:  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2400/Tic-Tac-Toe-in-C

Comment: I'll try your solution and see what I can come up with.

Answer (score 0):

Using Frodo's advice I came up with a solution which is a lot simpler than what I was doing before.

I stored all winning combinations into an array. Then I checked each winning combo to see if each cell's value in that combo matched. Simple as that.

```
var winningNums = [
    [0,1,2],
    [3,4,5],
    [6,7,8],
    [0,3,6],
    [1,4,7],
    [2,5,8],
    [0,4,8],
    [2,4,6]
   ];


  //checks if values are the same
  $scope.checkResults = function(){
    var allCells = $scope.cells;
    for(var i = 0; i < winningNums.length; i++){
        var a = winningNums[i][0],b=winningNums[i][1],c=winningNums[i][2];
        var cell1 = allCells[a].value, cell2 = allCells[b].value, cell3 = allCells[c].value;
      if(cell1 == "" || cell2 == "" || cell3 == "" ){
        break;
      }
        if(cell1 === cell2 && cell2 === cell3 ){
            var winnerDiv = "<div><h1>" + cell1 + " is the winner</h1></div>";
          $(
"#wrapper").append(winnerDiv);
        }

      }

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

## This Answer Does not Use `jQuery`

Using an **array** similar to what's shown in the above  answer, we can just use a few different array **methods:**

```js
const WINNING_INDICES = [
  [0, 1, 2],
  [0, 3, 6],
  [0, 4, 8],
  [1, 4, 7],
  [2, 5, 8],
  [2, 4, 6],
  [3, 4, 5],
  [6, 7, 8],
];

function check4Winner(board, letter) {
  return WINNING_INDICES.some(winningIndices =>
    winningIndices.every(winningIndex => board[winningIndex] === letter),
  );
}

console.log(check4Winner(['X', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'X', '', '']), "X");
```

Here, I have passed in a hard-coded board that's a flat array. It represents the nine squares on a Tic-Tac-Toe board.

Summarily, we want to see if there is at least one instance (`some`) where all the indices of a given **element** (`winningIndices`) of `WINNING_INDICES`, when used with `board`, match the given letter (`"X"`).

Answer (score 0):

This is just the function of my code to determine who won in the game. I also use the winning combination numbers in my code.

```
      var i = -1;
      var WinnerChecker = setInterval(() =>{
      var p1 = 0, p2 = 0;
      i = i<TileCombos.length ? ++i : 0
      for(let j = 0; j<3; j++){
          if(player[TileCombos[i][j]].innerHTML == chk[0].innerHTML){
                  p1 += 1;
         }
           if(player[TileCombos[i][j]].innerHTML == chk[1].innerHTML){
                  p2 += 1;
         }
      }
      if(p1 == 3){
        console.log('PLAYER 1 WON');
      }
      if(p2 == 3){
        console.log('PLAYER 2 WON');
      }    

      })
```